# Cannot freeze transformations in Maya

Tags: 3d, animation, transform, maya

I'm trying to freeze transforms in Maya, for an object that has animated children, but is not animated itself. (Explanation will follow in detail)

First of all, is this possible? Because it should be, so my intuition tells.

My hierarchy is like this :

```
ParentObject
- ChildObject
```

`ChildObject` has animations, however `ParentObject` hasn't any. I removed them manually from the Graph Editor. I also deleted all history on `ParentObject`, but still, when I select ParentObject from the Outliner, and call `DeleteAllHistory; FreezeTransformations;` I get the error message : `// Error : line 0: Freeze Transform was not applied because ChildObject.translateY has incoming connection`

It doesn't even make sense because I select Parent, and not the Child. Does it automatically selects the child. If so, how can I prevent this behaviour?

Thanks for any help !

### Edit:

One possible solution is to select the Parent and group it, so add a grandparent. But I don't want this to go on, until I have

```
GrandGrandGrandGrandParent
- GrandGrandGrandParent
 - GrandGrandParent
  - etc
```

so I want to know what I'm doing wrong, so I can fix it in later, probably more complicated situations. Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

No and yes, freezing moves space. Thus the numeric values of any child spaces are moved around loosing meaning. To protect users from themselves its not allowed, and it does not make sense. Spaces under children are not affected as long as the child can be resolved, because the child space didnt change. (children are defined in their parents spaces)

You can re shift/scale the children, unless the space was rotated. Or you could bake down the transformation to world space and back. This is a bit error prone tough and you would need to write the script yourself.

PS. I keep telling people freeze isnt a tool you want to use to organize channels for easy editing. You should avoid freezing at all cost, once your data is comitted freezing is rarely possible. So once you go and freeze or animate your mind better be made.

Comment: Good answer, however I tend to notice that freezing transformations BEFORE parenting the objects takes care of issues like these.

Comment: @ckpepper02 Yes, because thetes no external data that relies on the position of the coordinates. Once external data goes in its too late to start freezing or the data changes meaning. I find that people freeze more for mystical reasons than practical or technical reasons. So many perform these rituals without knowing what they do. Freezing is not well understood outside very technical users.

Comment: By the way if somebody wants to ask the question what does freeze do ill explain it and if you understand the answer youd know why this problem arises.